# "Cost per Lead Quality" Score

Tags: finance

I'm a marketing manager and would like to calculate a cost per lead quality "score." I run a number of marketing campaigns, and I've figured out how to calculate a quality percentage for each campaign (i.e. how likely leads are to become a sale). Now I'd like to make a connection between the quality percentage and the cost per lead, and obtain an overall "score."

So if the quality percent is a perfect 100%, and the cost per lead is $0, the campaign would have a perfect cost per lead quality score of 100 out of 100. And if the quality percent decreases, or if the cost per lead increases, the cost per lead quality score decreases accordingly to both factors. I realize that although there will be a score ceiling of a perfect 100, there will not be a score floor as cost per lead can be infinite.

Can anyone help me out with a formula to plug into Excel? It would be greatly appreciated!!!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know, if I have understood you right. But here is my attemption:

One score could be $s=100\cdot \frac{q}{1+c}, \ \ 0 < s \leq 100$

q= quality percent, $0\text{%} \leq q \leq 100 \text{%}$

c= cost per lead (in Dollars)

In this case you would have an index with a *value set* between 0 and 100. If $q=100\text{%}=1$ and $c=0$, then $s=100$. You could compare very easily the indices values for different values of q and c.

Edit: Definition set replaced by *value set*.

This index can be adjusted. c can have a positive exponent.